# Is there a way to encrypt c# source code?

Tags: windows-phone-7, obfuscation

I just migrated one of my app from iOS to WP7. I found that it is easy to decompile the source code of C# files. Is there a way or tool to encrypt C# source code?

Comment: What files are you asking about? .cs files? If you encrypt them, how will the compiler compile them?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it is not possible to get the assemblies of an application from the device, so whilst it might be trivial to have source, it sounds like you're over engineering it a touch.

Comment: In fact, it appears that you cannot even get to the isolated storage of any applications installed via the store (let alone any assemblies, even for applications installed by a developer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are looking to protect your source, you may take a look at this

http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227255%28VS.80%29.aspx